# This is the task manager screenshot for my server. Will increasing RAM make a difference?

Tags: memory, apache-http-server, mysql

The server runs XAMPP (Apache and MySQL mainly). Lately the concurrent user count has increased, and the server crawls and sputters during peak load. It only has 4GB RAM though. So, my question is will increasing RAM make a difference?

[image: Server task manager screenshot]

Comment: This machine is showing three fourths of its RAM "available". That is not a machine that is experiencing memory pressure. To confirm this, you could look at the page fault rates - especially the hard fault rate. If these are low, adding RAM will not help. CPU usage does not appear to be a problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing MySQL max connection has  a direct effect on RAM, as it  increases the number of file descriptors that **mysqld** requires

```
max_connections = (Available RAM - Global Buffers) / Thread Buffers
```

To get the global and thread buffers

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';
```

Just have a look in the number of opened tables

```
mysqladmin status 
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Opened_tables';
```

**Note:** It is always better to have separate servers for Apache and MySQL. Increasing RAM will definitely help